# Why am I getting a TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error when using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to use redux w/ react but I'm running into a TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error. I can't figure out why I keep getting this error and it only happens on the page that uses this Survey component so I know that it's definitely redux that's messing up somewhere. Some help would be really appreciated.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import surveyReducer from './reducers/survey-reducer.js'
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const store = createStore(
  surveyReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
),document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../scss/Survey.scss';

class Survey extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let root = document.querySelector('#root');
    root.className = '';
    root.classList.toggle('survey-root');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <NavBar />
        <div>

        </div>
      </>
      )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    questions: state
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    chooseAnswer: (action) => dispatch(action)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Survey);
```

```js
export default function surveyReducer (state = {
    Q1: '',
    Q2: '',
    Q3: '',
    Q4: '',
    Q5: '',
    Q6: '',
    Q7: '',
    Q8: '',
    Q9: '',
    Q10: '',
    Q11: '',
    Q12: '',
    Q13: '',
    Q14: '',
    Q15: '',
    Q16: '',
    Q17: ''
  }, action) {
  switch (action.question) {
    case 'Q1':
      return {...state, Q1: action.answer};
    case 'Q2':
      return {...state, Q2: action.answer};
    case 'Q3':
      return {...state, Q3: action.answer};
    case 'Q4':
      return {...state, Q4: action.answer};
    case 'Q5':
      return {...state, Q5: action.answer};
    case 'Q6':
      return {...state, Q6: action.answer};
    case 'Q7':
      return {...state, Q7: action.answer};
    case 'Q8':
      return {...state, Q8: action.answer};
    case 'Q9':
      return {...state, Q9: action.answer};
    case 'Q10':
      return {...state, Q10: action.answer};
    case 'Q11':
      return {...state, Q11: action.answer};
    case 'Q12':
      return {...state, Q12: action.answer};
    case 'Q13':
      return {...state, Q13: action.answer};
    case 'Q14':
      return {...state, Q14: action.answer};
    case 'Q15':
      return {...state, Q15: action.answer};
    case 'Q16':
      return {...state, Q16: action.answer};
    case 'Q17':
      return {...state, Q17: action.answer};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    chooseAnswer: (action) => dispatch(action)
  };
}  
in this part which action are you dispatching you haven't defined any action ?

Comment: What is classList.toggle?? If it’s a list don’t you think you should use index? Like classList[0].toggle

Comment: disregard the classList, that's so I can target my root for my scss file, that's not what's breaking the code.

Comment: i haven't dispatched anything yet, i'm just defining the dispatch so when i use it i can call this.props.chooseAnswer(action), where action would be an object with keys of question and answer. On the error page it seems to point to my index.js file...i know dispatch and state would be available to me by default if i just did connect()(Survey)...but I still get that error even when I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the versions of the dependencies, my react package version wasn't compatible with the redux I had installed. What a headache.